# Question of understanding regarding the processes and queue of the round robin algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling, round-robin

**First Question: Round Robin (Quantum = 1)**

Assumed in time unit 1 the queue is (A, B) and in time unit 2 the process C is added. 
What is the queue in time unit 2?

A: Queue = (B, A, C) 
 B: Queue = (B, C, A)

**Second Question: Round Robin (Quantum = 4)**

Assumed in time unit 1 the queue is (A, B, C) and the processes have following service times:

Process A: 2 Quants 
 Process B: 1 Quant 
 Process C: 2 Quants

**Which of the following procedures is correct?**

**Procedure 1:** 
 Process A has 4 quants available. 
 Process A is completed after 2 quants.
 Process B has 4 quants available. 
Process B is completed after 1 quant.
Process C has 4 quants available.
Process C is completed after 2 quants.

**Procedure 2:** 
Process A has 4 quants available.
Process A is completed after 2 quants.
Process B has 6 quants available. (2 A + 4 B) 
Process B is completed after 1 quant.
Process C has 9 quants available. (1 A + 4 B + 4 C) 
Process C is completed after 2 quants.

**Procedure 3:** 
Process A has 4 quants available.
Process A is completed after 2 quants.
Process B has 2 quants available. (2 A)
Process B is completed after 1 quant.
Process C has 1 quant available. (1 A) 
Process C uses 1 quant. 
The clock is reset to 4 quants again. 
Process C is completed after another 1 quant.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer to the first Question in my notes:

"Job is put back at the end of the queue. All jobs that created in the meantime, come into the queue before this job."

So the correct answer for the first question is B.

According to Quora, the correct answer to the second question is Procedure 1. Please correct me if it isn't correct.

https://www.quora.com/If-the-process-finished-before-a-time-quantum-in-round-robin-does-the-process-wait-for-the-given-time-quantum-or-does-it-get-executed-without-waiting